# React+Typescript - Proper way to handle communication with children in small components

Tags: html, reactjs, typescript

I want to create a NavBar component that has NavBar.Item children that defines the buttons in the navbar, something like this:

```
<NavBar>
    <NavBar.Item text="Main menu"/>
    <NavBar.Item text="Settings"/>
    <NavBar.Item text="About"/>
</NavBar>
```

Obviously, when you click one option, that option is highlighted and all others are not. This requires each NavBar.Item to handle its own input and communicate with its siblings through their parents. What would be the correct / standard / accepted way to achieve this. Two options I have thought about are:

- Wrapping the  in a context, so children can share, modify and listen to that context. That looks like an easy solution but I'm not sure if spamming contexts every time I write a component that has "custom" children is a good practice.
- Having NavBar intercept its children and handle everything itself (i.e. add the onClick event on the children itself, and manipulating all its children from that onClick). This option looks way too hacky for me to be a correct solution to such a common problem.

If someone can point me in the right direction for this, I'd be thankful.

Answer (score 0):

For your case, you can use `renderProps` feature.

https://react.dev/reference/react/Children#calling-a-render-prop-to-customize-rendering

And React-Router by default has the feature you want.

https://reactrouter.com/en/main/components/nav-link

Please check them.